# Django: When creating a new project, "django-admin.py: command not found" Error pops up

Tags: python, django, set

I've been following the tutorial on the django website and have been running into a problem regarding setting up Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I've installed Django through their guide using setup.py, but when I run "django-admin.py startproject mysite" on the terminal, it outputs the error "-bash: django-admin.py: command not found". I've tried django-admin as per some google searches and some searches have told me to try the following commands

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/local/django/trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py django-admin.py
```

but I continue to get "ln: django-admin.py: Permission denied" in that case.

I use the macports Python and was wondering if I could get any help regarding the matter. Thank you very much in advance!

SOLUTION:
Thanks Doug!

After some googling I found: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls which told me a similar solution. I needed to link to my bin and give permissions. Also the command needed to be run with django-admin2.6.py otherwise would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/django/trunk/django/bin

Answer (score 0):

For solving the 'Permission Denied' error:

```
chmod +x path/to/bin/django-admin.py
```

Running the above in Terminal (edited to your own file) solved my own 'Permission Denied' error while setting up Django in a virtualenv on a Webfaction server.